# Magento 2 Class *Factory does not exist

Tags: magento2

I was trying to install a plugin and I removed var/generation and var/cache/*. I've checked the MAGE_MODE and I'm in developer but now when I access the front-end and the admin I get random errors saying mean things like:
*`Class Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory does not exist`*

*Class Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\OrderFactory* does not exist

Some of the classes are being created, but not all. I've tried clearing cache again, and the generation folder but then I just get the same errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: check the rights on the var/generation folder

Comment: it says drwxrwxrw- 5

Comment: I had to clean the var/generation folder a few times, go to the home page first, the clean, then admin, then login, then clean... and it worked...?? I don't understand this

Comment: Definitely permissions within 'var/generation' folder.

Answer (score 26):

Magento 2 generates Factory classes inside `var/generation` directory. So, if there is folder permission issue or folder owner issue with that directory then the factory class cannot be generated and you get such error.

When you clear `var/generation` directory and set appropriate permission to it then this error should be solved.

See more on [Code generation in Magento 2](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/code-generation/)

Comment: Could be also `var/di` or `var/cache`, see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_wrong-mysql.html

Comment: Funny how it always come back to basics. Lol, I need to stop having denials.

Comment: @Mukesh Chapagain Code generation in Magento 2 link is not working. Please add the appropriate link.

Comment: @SavanDholu Updated the answer with a working link. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

For me, i removed `var/generation` folder then i ran `magento setup:di:compile` which generated all necessary classes.

(in my case : Then i was encountered with cache issue, i removed initial cache folder.)

Then it solved my issue. Cheers !!

Comment: needed to change files owner at the end

Answer (score 9):

In magento new versions like 2.2.2 and above this code generation path changed to

```
<Magento root folder>/generated
```

so you need to check permissions for this folder as well. You need to run following command at the root of Magento installation directory will resolve this issue:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 generated/
```

Comment: clear cache as well in start

Comment: its work for me

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 creates the factory classes in the `var/generation` folder and if you add a new parameter in your `__construct()` and it's Factory class does not exists then Magento 2 throws the above error message. Even though there are few solutions give already for you question, i can suggest you another solution which does not require you to clear your generation folder. Please use the below command after any change is made related to Factory classes:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

This command can be more useful on production server.

Answer (score -1):

It's just `<magento-root>/var/` folder permission issue.

Execute below command using CLI mode

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/
```

Answer (score -2):

Class ...Factory does not exist means your model class not loaded.
As Magento 2 based on modular programming so we need to specify the model class where we want to use explicitly.
We can use our model class in two types:

1.by "use"

```
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

public function __construct(CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
{
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
}
```

2. Directly

   ```
   public function __construct(Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory){

   $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;

   }
   ```

When you hit the URL(http://domain.com/your module frontname) of your plugin on browser than the Magento generate the code for your module as below:

```
\var\generation\Your Vendor Directory\Your Module Directory\Controller
\var\generation\Your Vendor Directory\Your Module Directory\Model
```

In your case you need to check the "CustomerFactory" and "OrderFactory" is used as above format or not.

Answer (score -2):

Give 777 permission and change ownership to www-data of **generated/code** folder
and then run the command  `sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile` clear cache and boom your problem is solved

Comment: setting permissions to 777 is a security vulverability