# Class Magento\ImportExport\Model\ExportFactory does not exist

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am trying to export the products from admin panel but CSV file not generating anywhere. When I tried to run this command
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor
It generates the error :

```
`In ClassReader.php line 35:
                                                                 
  Class Magento\ImportExport\Model\ExportFactory does not exist  
                                                                 

In ClassReader.php line 29:
                                                                 
  Class Magento\ImportExport\Model\ExportFactory does not exist  
`
```

This Magento 2.3 version and fresh installation with demo products data. I want to edit products in bulk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some steps like :-

so you need to check permissions for this folder as well. You need to run following command at the root of Magento installation directory will resolve this issue:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 generated/
```

And then ran `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`.This command work will generate all factory classes.

And get more infomation check this link :-

[Magento 2 Class *Factory does not exist](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103312/magento-2-class-factory-does-not-exist/240577)

Comment: Thanks it solved the issue. This was only files permissions issue

Answer (score 0):

if you are in production mode then please run

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

it will generate all factory classes for you

if you have installed Magento on your local for development I recommend changing your environment from `default` to `developer`

using

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```